# Intent.ACTION_PICK closes Activity on onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have `Activity A` which starts `Activity B`.

Then, in activity B there's a button to "select a

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*"); startActivityForResult(intent,
SELECT_PICTURE);
```

And then, I have the function

```
@Override 

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int
resultCode, Intent data) {...
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes when `onActivityResult` is called, `Activity B` restarts, and sometimes it just goes back to activity A, even before going through `onActivityResult`.

I've been reading that it could happen due to Ram problems, but how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your logs.

Comment: What Activities are being launched by your `Action_PICK` intent? If they are 3rd party apps there's no guarantee they'll work with `startActivityForResult`

Comment: @Squonk it's the default image picker for Android. It's a button on screen that calls the Intent.ACTION_PICK. And sometimes it works, sometimes it restarts, sometimes it goes back to Activity A...

Comment: As @AndyFaizan commented - post your logcat and post your full `onActivityResult` code. You might also want to put some extra logging into your code as well so you can track sequence of events.

Comment: @Squonk it doesn't matter the onActivityResult code, sometimes it works, sometimes not. And even if I delete everything and just left {} it goes back to Activity A... Also tried to just do a Log.d(..) on the onActivityResult and it doesn't log anything.. The only thing it logs is when the intent.ACTION_PICKER starts it says: IInputConnectionWrapper(16003): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

Answer (score 0):

Check if you add at the manifest

```
        android:noHistory="true"
```

to the Activity B
if so please remove it
you can't use this flag and use OnActivityResult
because this flag cause your activity end as soon as the activity is going to background

If ti not a problem of no history it might be related to the Action of the intent
Try use this :

```
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

and onActivityResult

```
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
```